# How to translate a csv file faster into another language?

Tags: python, xml, csv, time-complexity, google-translate

**My approach**

Converting csv file to Xml and translating it into required language and again converting into csv file.

**Code**

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from googletrans import Translator
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETree
import pandas as pd
import csv

#csv to xml
df= pd.read_csv('Salary Dataset.csv')
with open('outputf.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(df.to_xml())


tree = ET.parse('outputf.xml')
for elem in tree.iter():
    #print(elem.tag, elem.text)
    if(elem.text):
      translator=Translator()
      translation=translator.translate(elem.text,dest="fr").text
      #elem.text.replace(elem.text,translation)
      elem.text=translation
      #print(elem.text)
tree.write('outputfr.xml', xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding="utf8")


xmlp = ETree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
Tree = ETree.parse('outputf.xml',parser=xmlp)
#Hit and trial methods
#xml='/content/output.xml'
#xmltest = ET.fromstring(xml.encode("utf-8"))
#Tree = ETree.parse(xmltest)
#Tree = ETree.parse('/content/outputfr.xml')

root = Tree.getroot()
A=[]
for ele in root:
  B = {}
  for i in list(ele):
    B.update({i.tag: i.text})
    A.append(B)
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
writer = csv.writer(open('600.csv', 'w'))
df.to_csv('600.csv')

print("XML FILE CONVERTED SUCESSFULLY")
```

Basically time taken by this code is more 25 min minutes. Is there a way to reduce the time complexity in this code. It takes more time where the translator function is used.[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

| Company | Job | Salaries | Location | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MU Sigma | Data Scientist | 105 | Bangalore | â‚¹6,43,232/yr |
| IBM | Data Scientist | 125 | Bangalore | â‚¹6,21,651/yr |
| TATA | Data Scientist | 200 | Bangalore | â‚¹3,67,282/yr |
| Flipkart | Data Scientist | 100 | Bangalore | â‚¹8,90,567/yr |
| Amazon | Data Scientist | 90 | Bangalore | â‚¹5,45,521/yr |

Comment: Please feel free to suggest changes in code where ever required.

Comment: I thought going through xml will be faster compared to csv. Is there a way to directly translate it. Please help.

Comment: Please show us what's in Salary Dataset.csv (at least a few lines).

Comment: i added the image in the section.Hope it helps

Comment: Will keep that in mind from now. I have made changes and uploaded the table.

Comment: The best way is to post the raw CSV contents. Now it is not clear what the delimiter is and we cannot copy-paste the contents of the table into a .csv file.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: you told to upload the contents of csv file and I have added it and the table are just for your reference as it looks like this in csv file. I hope you can find any dataset related to salary and based on my given code you can make changes. The thing is that I just wanted to know how to make it fast?

Comment: There could be many reasons for the slowness. For example: 1) You have a  bad internet connection 2) The dataset is very large 3) Perhaps Google throttles traffic if you make many requests in a short time. I don't know. However, I posted an answer with simplified code that does not use an intermediary XML file. Perhaps that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using an intermediary XML file seems unnecessary. Just create an output file with the translated items of each row in the input file. Also note that only one instance of `Translator` is needed. Here is how you could do it:

```py
import csv
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

def translate(s):
    return translator.translate(s, dest="fr").text

with open('dataset.csv', "r") as infile, open('dataset_fr.csv', "w") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in reader:
        translated_row = [translate(item) for item in row]
        writer.writerow(translated_row)
```

Comment: I am new to this, and the code you gave is taking more time.

Comment: You wrote "Please feel free to suggest changes in code where ever required". That is exactly what I did. And as I already wrote, there could be many reasons for slowness. For example: 1) You have a bad internet connection 2) The dataset is very large 3) Perhaps Google throttles traffic if you make many requests in a short time. I don't know. Did you research these options at all? It is not possible to provide help or explanations for everything in single answer.